# Snowflake/SQL Duplicate Records based on values within comma seperated list

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataframe of User IDs and Tags as shown below under 'Current Data' .

*The Goal*:

I want to be able to duplicate records per each value under the **tags** column. As you can see in the target output, user ID 21 is repeated 3x for each of the three tags that are in the source 'TAGS' - everything is duplicated except the Tag column - 1 Record per item in the comma separated list.

*Issue*:

I looked at using the [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) functionality in snowflake but it doesn't work in my use case as not all the tags are consistently in some kind of order and in some cases, the cell is also blank.

**Current Data:**

```
USER_ID CITY    STATUS  PPL     TAGS
21      LA      checked 6       bad ui/ux,dashboards/reporting,pricing
32      SD      checked 9       buggy,laggy
21      ATL     checked 9   
234     MIA     checked 5       glitchy, bad ui/ux, horrible
```

***The target:***

```
    USER_ID CITY    STATUS  PPL     TAGS
    21      LA      checked 6       bad ui/ux
    21      LA      checked 6       dashboards/reporting
    21      LA      checked 6       Pricing
    32      SD      checked 9       buggy
    32      SD      checked 9       laggy
    21      ATL     checked 9   
    234     MIA     checked 5       glitchy
    234     MIA     checked 5       bad ui/ux
    234     MIA     checked 5       horrible
```

Sql:

```
select table1.value 
from table(split_to_table('a.b', '.')) as table1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SPLIT_TO_TABLE** works. Below is the query using your sample data:

```
select USER_ID, CITY, STATUS, PPL, VALUE
from (values
      (21,'LA','checked',6,'bad ui/ux,dashboards/reporting,pricing')
        ,(32,'SD','checked',9,'buggy,laggy')
        ,(21,'ATL','checked',9,'')
        ,(234,'MIA','checked',5,'glitchy, bad ui/ux, horrible')
    ) as tbl (USER_ID,CITY,STATUS,PPL,TAGS)
, lateral split_to_table(tbl.tags,',');
```

**Result:**

```
USER_ID CITY    STATUS  PPL VALUE
21  LA  checked 6   bad ui/ux
21  LA  checked 6   dashboards/reporting
21  LA  checked 6   pricing
32  SD  checked 9   buggy
32  SD  checked 9   laggy
21  ATL checked 9   
234 MIA checked 5   glitchy
234 MIA checked 5    bad ui/ux
234 MIA checked 5    horrible
```